# Using OAuth on Bluemix with Liberty

Tags: oauth, ibm-cloud

I would like to use a JEE application on Bluemix using OAuth Authentication/Authorization. I found this article:

[Develop an OAuth-protected resource application in Bluemix](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-oauthregistry-app/)

But neither the example is running nor there is a feature in Bluemix console to create an "Add-On" called "App User Registry".

It looks like that this feature deprecated, but I cannot find a replacement. There are several documents on SSO, SAML, "Cloud Directory", but no simple "getting started" article, like the above one, with code examples for resource server and client.

Where can I find such a replacement?

Comment: The OAuth Service has been removed from the Bluemix catalog, and so far there is no service that provides the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The document and sample for Liberty profile could be used for bluemix, here are some articles:
1. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1502_odonnell/1502_odonnell.html
2. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1305_odonnell2/1305_odonnell2.html